# Use escape codes immediately followed by numbers

Tags: bash, escaping

I need to write something like `"0x12345"` in a file using a bash script. The hex value is a variable, and the quotes have to be in the file.

To echo a quote, I use `\042`, and I use `$1` for the hex. So I have something like :

`echo -e "\042$1\042" > file.txt`

This works perfectly if `$1` is starts with a letter, but because it starts with a 0, the escape code is interpreted as `\0420` or something like that, and it writes `^Px123"` in the file instead of `"0x123"`

How can I write exactly "0x.." ? I can't add a space or another character in front of the number. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: Using `echo -e "\x22$1\x22"` would have worked; since the hexadecimal sequence can be at most 2 characters, it wouldn't "absorb" the first digit of `$1` like `\042` did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need `-e`.

Just use:

```
s="0x12345"
echo "\"$s\""

"0x12345"
```

Or else use more portable `printf`:

```
printf "\042%s\042\n" "$s"

"0x12345"
```

Comment: Thank you ! I used `-e` because I needed to use `\n` initially. Are `\"` and `\042` exactly equivalent ?

Comment: Yes they are same